# Random word not returning

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple hangman game, and I'm already stuck on one of the first few steps.

This is the code I got so far:

```
import random
word_list = ["Bee", "Fuzzy", "Existentialism"]


def get_word():
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    return word.upper()

print(get_word)
```

When I run it, I expected it to return one of the words from word_list. But instead it returns this when I try to print it out:

```
<function get_word at 0x0138D2F8>
```

Comment: ir's `print(get_word())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_word` is a function, so you need to call it with the `()` at the end. e.g. `get_word()` instead of just `get_word`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine except `print(get_word)`

Just use `print(get_word())`

You missing brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(get_word())`. `get_word` is a function to call it in python you should use `get_word()`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
def get_word():
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    print(word.upper())
get_word()
```

In this, you just need to call the function since you are printing inside the function instead of returning the value

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
def get_word():
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    return word.upper()
fun_call = get_word()
print(fun_call)
```

Here you always need to call the function and then print it. You can also print it directly in the print statement

Answer (score 0):

the `get_word()` is a function, so to call on it, you have to put a `()` at the end of it.
when you use `print(get_word)`, it is printing the info on the function, not the result of the function itself.